# OpenCL run remotely: "No protocol specified" message but program runs normally

Tags: c++, c++11, ssh, opencl

I am working on a remote GPU and I connect to it using ssh. 
I am running a C++ program deploying the OpenCL library. Since yesterday my program (which before run fine) started to print the following message

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
```

when i call the function:

```
if(clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &n_platforms) != CL_SUCCESS){
        cerr << "error: no platform" << endl;
        exit(1);
    };
```

the weird thing is that if there occurs an error then the program should print "error non platform" and then exit. Instead it keeps running normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem occurs whenever someone is working locally on the computer.